# Python regex with \w does not work

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to have a regex to find a phrase and two words preceding it if there are two words.
For example I have the string (one sentence per line):

> Chevy is my car and Rusty is my horse.
>   My car is very pretty my dog is red.

If i use the regex:

```
re.finditer(r'[\w+\b|^][\w+\b]my car',txt)
```

I do not get any match.

If I use the regex:

```
re.finditer(r'[\S+\s|^][\S+\s]my car',txt)
```

I am getting:
's my car' and '. My car' (I am ignoring case and using multi-line)

Why is the regex with \w+\b not finding anything? It should find two words and 'my car'
How can I get two complete words before 'my car' if there are two words. If there is only one word preceding my car, I should get it. If there are no words preceding it I should get only  'my car'.  In my string example I should get: 'Chevy is my car' and 'My car' (no preceding words here)

Comment: Please show the exact Python call you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `r'[\w+\b|^][\w+\b]my car` regex, `[\w+\b|^]` matches 1 symbol that is either a word char, a `+`, a backdpace, `|`, or `^` and `[\w+\b]` matches 1 symbol that is either a word char, or `+`, or a backspace.

The point is that inside a character class, quantifiers and a lot (**but not all**) special characters match literal symbols. E.g. `[+]` matches a plus symbol, `[|^]` matches either a `|` or `^`. Since you want to match a *sequence*, you need to provide a sequence of subpatterns outside of a character class.

It seems as if you intended to use `\b` as a word boundary, however, `\b` inside a character class matches only a backspace character.

To *find two words and 'my car'*, you can use, for example

```
\S+\s+\S+\s+my car
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY4wC6/2) (here, `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace symbols, and `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespaces, and the 2 occurrences of these 2 consecutive subpatterns match these symbols as a *sequence*).

To make the sequences before `my car` optional, just use a `{0,2}` quantifier like this:

```
(?:\S+[ \t]+){0,2}my car
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY4wC6/3) (to be used with the `re.IGNORECASE` flag). See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/B930oh):

```
import re
txt  = 'Chevy is my car and Rusty is my horse.\nMy car is very pretty my dog is red.'
print(re.findall(r'(?:\S+[ \t]+){0,2}my car', txt, re.I))
```

**Details**:

- `(?:\S+[ \t]+){0,2}` - 0 to 2 sequences of 1+ non-whitespaces followed with 1+ space or tab symbols (you may also replace it with `[^\S\r\n]` to match any horizontal space or `\s` if you also plan to match linebreaks).
- `my car` - a literal text `my car`.

Comment: But careful, in the regex `[^|]` the caret *does* have a special meaning, albeit a different one - it makes the character class match any character that is *not* present in the class (e. g., anything but a `|` character in this case)...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes, actually, that part should be described in the [SO documenation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1757/character-classes). Still, there is no such an explanation yet.

Comment: I was wondering to ask if you should expand on why `\b` "between" words behaves not as expected, but since it seems to be added by the OP as part of a "random inserting codes until it works" routine, I'll forego it...

Comment: If you have a string with multiple lines, and the value you need is at the beginning of the line, you can use [`re.findall(r'^(?:\S+\s+){0,2}my car', txt, re.I | re.M)`](https://ideone.com/diROtF)

Comment: The proposed regex is working correctly if I am processing one sentence at the time. If execute the regex with a string of multiple lines and 'my car' at different places. It is not working correctly. I need to have the 'start of sequence' as an option.  This regex r'(\S+\s+|^){0,2}my car' seems to work better.

Comment: Maybe [`re.findall(r'(?:\S+[ \t]+){0,2}my car', txt, re.I)`](https://ideone.com/B930oh)? Discard the `^` altogether then. Instead of `\s` that matches a newline, you can use a simpler `[ \t]` character class to avoid matching line breaks.

Comment: I will adjust the answer then.